# Pandas DF - Find a sequence in consecutive columns in a row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data frame and I want to find [c, d] in columns next to each other (exact sequence).

In the example below the rows 0 and 2 have [c, d] in columns next to each other.

```
  A B C D
0 a c d e
1 a d e c
2 b e c d
3 c a d e
```

I have tried df.eq('c') & df.eq('d') but this will find 'c' and 'd' in any order in a row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shift values by row for one of the comparisons, and then check if both conditions are true at the same location:

```
(df.shift(axis=1).eq('c') & df.eq('d')).any(1)

#0     True
#1    False
#2     True
#3    False
#dtype: bool
```

Comment: And if we want to find them in the row regardless of the position but as per the sequence.  so search for [c d] would not return row 1 where we have cols like [a d e c]. Not sure if this should be a new question.